# Melhorar a performance de uma query

Tags: sql, mysql

Como eu poderia melhorar essa query, que me retorna o top 10 de vendas para montar um gráfico, de forma que ela processe mais rapidamente?

```
set @startDate :='2015-01-03';
set @endDate :='2015-05-31';
set @dst_id:=1;


SELECT
  SUM(vnd_quantidade) as quantidade,
  (SUM(vnd_faturamento) / (SELECT
     SUM(vnd_faturamento) as valor from
                  venda where vnd_dt
                      between @startDate and @endDate 
                     and dst_id=@dst_id) * 100) as porcentagem_tooltip,
     SUM(vnd_faturamento) as faturamento,
    (SUM(vnd_faturamento) / (SELECT
         SUM(valores.valor) as Total from
         ((SELECT sum(vnd_quantidade) as qtd,
                  sum(vnd_faturamento) as valor,
                  prd_id from venda where vnd_dt 
                  between @startDate and @endDate 
                  and dst_id=@dst_id group by prd_id order by qtd desc
           limit 10) valores)) * 100) as total_grafico,
venda.prd_id, produto.prd_nome as Produto
from venda 
INNER JOIN produto ON(produto.prd_id=venda.prd_id)
where vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate and dst_id=@dst_id
group by prd_id order by porcentagem_tooltip desc,
quantidade desc,
faturamento desc 
limit 10
```

Gostaria de evitar tantas SUBQUERYS.

Minha tabela está apresentando algo assim:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|quantidade|porcentagem|tooltip_faturamento|total_grafico|prd_id|Produto|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1499    | 11,754075 |     686091,43     |  21,208158  | 162  | 27285 |
|  2630    | 9,838371  |     574270,77     |  17,751606  | 178  | 27395 |
|  1183    | 7,123907  |     415826,15     |  12,853836  | 174  | 27392 |
|  2053    | 7,097845  |     414304,88     |  12,806811  | 179  | 27396 |
|  1677    | 6,852019  |     399955,87     |  12,363261  | 207  | 27915 |
|  8526    | 5,728544  |     334378,08     |  10,336149  | 14   | 16520 |
|  5261    | 5,707067  |     333124,42     |  10,297396  | 4    | 15970 |
|  764     | 4,297695  |     250858,68     |  7,754434   | 175  | 27393 |
|  898     | 3,415646  |     199373        |  6,162931   | 208  | 27916 |
|  447     | 3,342078  |     195078,84     |  6,030192   | 163  | 27286 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Com EXPLAIN, obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  |      select_type     |  table    |  type | possible_keys |  key  | key_len |       ref         |  rows  |                    Extra                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   |       PRIMARY        |  venda    | range | prd_id,vnd_dt | vnd_dt|    3    |                   |  16297 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   |       PRIMARY        | produto   | eq_ref| PRIMARY,prd_id|PRIMARY|    2    |DB123.venda.prd_id |    1   |                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3   | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | <derived4>|  ALL  |               |       |         |                   |   10   |                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  4   |        DERIVED       |  venda    | range |    vnd_dt     |vnd_dt |    3    |                   |  16297 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2   | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY |  venda    |  ALL  |    vnd_dt     |       |         |                   |  59245 | Using where                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

E estas são as tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `venda` (
  `vnd_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rvd_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clt_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dst_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fll_id` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `prd_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usr_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Vendedor',
  `ram_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uni_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `xls_id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `vnd_dt` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT 'Data da Venda',
  `vnd_quarter` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `vnd_nf` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `vnd_quantidade` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vnd_erro` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vnd_pts` enum('S','N') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `vnd_pts_combinacao` enum('S','N') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `vnd_pts_frequencia` enum('S','N') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `vnd_obs` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `vnd_produto_obs` varchar(155) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `vnd_faturamento` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vnd_unitario` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `vnd_clt_faturamento` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `vnd_faturamento_net` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `vnd_clt_unitario` double DEFAULT '0',
  `vnd_dt_cadastro` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vnd_id`,`rvd_id`,`dst_id`,`prd_id`,`usr_id`),
  KEY `rvd_id` (`rvd_id`),
  KEY `prd_id` (`prd_id`),
  KEY `vnd_dt` (`vnd_dt`),
  KEY `vnd_quantidade` (`vnd_quantidade`),
  KEY `vnd_pts` (`vnd_pts`),
  KEY `vnd_erro` (`vnd_erro`),
  KEY `ram_id` (`ram_id`),
  KEY `uni_id` (`uni_id`),
  KEY `xls_id` (`xls_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=59246 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;



CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `prd_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tip_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lob_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgm_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lnh_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fml_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `prd_nome` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Part Number',
  `prd_categoria` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prd_ativo` enum('S','N') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `prd_erro` enum('S','N') COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`prd_id`),
  KEY `prd_id` (`prd_id`),
  KEY `produto_FKIndex1` (`tip_id`),
  KEY `produto_FKIndex2` (`lob_id`),
  KEY `produto_FKIndex3` (`sgm_id`),
  KEY `produto_FKIndex4` (`lnh_id`),
  KEY `produto_FKIndex5` (`fml_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=293 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: É complicado indicar uma melhora na query sem ver ao menos o DDL das tabelas.

Comment: A primeira coisa a fazer é verificar se os campos que fazem parte das somas, groups e condições, estão sendo indexados. Segundo, evite LEFT JOIN, prefira o INNER (se possível). Terceiro você pode evitar os order by nas querys com group by e se realmente for necessário, jogá-las para as consultas mais externas. Quarto, crie funções para realizar os cálculos repetitivos, uma vez que o SGDB provavelmente irá indexar este procedimento apenas alterando as variáveis. Isto já deve ajudar bastante.

Comment: Coloquei as tabelas para melhorar a questão.

Comment: @IvanFerrer porque o uso do LEFT JOIN? Pela lógica não tem como ter vendas sem produtos. Na minha opinião você já poderia começar colocando INNER JOIN no lugar do LEFT JOIN. Tente explicar melhor o que realmente você quer buscar na Query.

Comment: Coloquei, mas eu gostaria de evitar o excesso de subquerys.

Comment: Inclua o execution plan da sua query. coloque um `EXPLAIN` antes do SELECT e vá em [edit] pergunta.

Comment: @gmsantos coloquei, e também coloquei as tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o seu SQL, as SubQuerys não são dependentes da Query principal. Dessa forma você pode usar variáveis "pre definidas" com os valores das SubQuerys garantindo assim uma única execução das SubQuerys.

**Editado**

Você também pode melhorar o desempenho fazendo o join só no final depois dos cálculos.

```
set @startDate :='2015-01-03';
set @endDate :='2015-05-31';
set @dst_id:=1;

SELECT
    @total1 := SUM(vnd_faturamento)
from venda 
    where 
        vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
        and dst_id=@dst_id;

SELECT
    @total2 := SUM(valores.valor)
from (
    SELECT sum(vnd_quantidade) as qtd,
        sum(vnd_faturamento) as valor,
        prd_id 
    from venda 
    where 
        vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
        and dst_id=@dst_id 
    group by 
        prd_id 
    order by 
        qtd desc
    limit 10
) valores;


SELECT 
    VendaComp.*
    , produto.prd_nome as Produto
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(vnd_quantidade) as quantidade,
        (SUM(vnd_faturamento) / @total1 * 100) as porcentagem_tooltip,
        SUM(vnd_faturamento) as faturamento,
        (SUM(vnd_faturamento) / @total2 * 100) as total_grafico,
        venda.prd_id
    from 
        venda 
    where 
        vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
        and dst_id=@dst_id
    group by 
        prd_id 
    limit 10
) VendaComp
    INNER JOIN produto 
    ON(produto.prd_id=VendaComp.prd_id)
order by 
    porcentagem_tooltip desc, 
    quantidade desc,
    faturamento desc;
```

Usando somente um SQL, com SubQuery

```
set @startDate :='2015-01-03';
set @endDate :='2015-05-31';
set @dst_id:=1;

SELECT 
    VendaComp.quantidade
    , (VendaComp.faturamento / VendaComp.total1 * 100) porcentagem_tooltip
    , VendaComp.faturamento
    , (VendaComp.faturamento / VendaComp.total2 * 100) total_grafico
    , VendaComp.prd_id
    , produto.prd_nome as Produto
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        (SELECT 
           SUM(`vnd_faturamento`)
         from venda 
            where 
                vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
                and dst_id=@dst_id
        ) AS total1,
        (SELECT
            SUM(valores.valor)
        from (
                SELECT 
                    sum(venda.vnd_quantidade) as qtd,
                    sum(venda.vnd_faturamento) as valor,
                    prd_id 
                from venda 
                where 
                    vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
                    and dst_id=@dst_id 
                group by 
                    prd_id 
                order by 
                    qtd desc
                limit 10
            ) valores
        ) total2
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SUM(vnd_quantidade) as quantidade,
            SUM(vnd_faturamento) as faturamento,
            venda.prd_id
        from 
            venda 
        where 
            vnd_dt between @startDate and @endDate 
            and dst_id=@dst_id
        group by 
            prd_id 
        limit 10
    ) T1
) VendaComp
    INNER JOIN produto 
    ON(produto.prd_id=VendaComp.prd_id)
ORDER BY
    porcentagem_tooltip desc, 
    quantidade desc,
    faturamento desc;
```

Comment: Parabéns! Você entendeu basicamente o problema, mas será que não dá pra melhorar isso tudo numa única query?

Comment: Execute com `EXPLAIN` as querys passadas com seus dados, você poderá analisar se houve melhora no desempenho.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, a última que você fez ficou perfeita, antes levava 7,212 segundos para carregar, agora está levando 1,288 segundos.